# Fatal Exception:Audio Recorder Thread and File not Found Exception

Tags: android, file, exception, audio, record

I am trying to implement audio recorder in my application.I tried this code and I got the error

```
11-27 08:21:12.394: W/System.err(1476): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/AudioRecorder/1385540472372.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-27 08:21:12.414: W/System.err(1476):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
 11-27 08:21:12.414: W/System.err(1476):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
11-27 08:21:12.454: W/System.err(1476):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
11-27 08:21:12.454: W/System.err(1476):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
11-27 08:21:12.464: W/System.err(1476):     at com.example.sms.OtherActivity.writeAudioDataToFile(OtherActivity.java:150)
11-27 08:21:12.484: W/System.err(1476):     at com.example.sms.OtherActivity.access$3(OtherActivity.java:141)
11-27 08:21:12.504: W/System.err(1476):     at com.example.sms.OtherActivity$3.run(OtherActivity.java:121)
11-27 08:21:12.524: W/System.err(1476):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-27 08:21:12.545: W/System.err(1476): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-27 08:21:12.564: W/System.err(1476):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-27 08:21:12.564: W/System.err(1476):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-27 08:21:12.614: W/System.err(1476):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
11-27 08:21:12.614: W/System.err(1476):     ... 7 more
 11-27 08:21:12.614: I/System.out(1476): 
 FATAL EXCEPTION:Audio Recorder Thread

11-27 08:21:12.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1476): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 08:21:12.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):at com.example.sms.OtherActivity.writeAudioDataToFile(OtherActivity.java:163)
11-27 08:21:12.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at com.example.sms.OtherActivity.access$3(OtherActivity.java:141)
11-27 08:21:12.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at com.example.sms.OtherActivity$3.run(OtherActivity.java:121)
11-27 08:21:12.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I get the file name as,I/System.out(1476):

```
Filename/mnt/sdcard/AudioRecorder/1385540472372.mp4Start writing to file[S@411b4610
```

And this is my code,

```
 private void startRecording() {

     recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
     RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
     RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);
     System.out.println("Start recording");
     recorder.startRecording();

     isRecording = true;

     recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {

     writeAudioDataToFile();
     System.out.println("In run recording");
     }
     }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
     recordingThread.start();
     }
```

writeAudioDataToFile method,

```
 private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
     // Write the output audio in byte

    String filePath=getFilename();
     System.out.print("Filename"+filePath);
     short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];

     FileOutputStream os = null;
     try {
     os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

     while (isRecording) {
     // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format
     recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
     System.out.println("Start writing to file" + sData.toString());
     try {
     // writes the data to file from buffer stores the voice buffer
     byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);

     os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);

     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }

     try {
     os.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }
```

getFileName method,

```
private String getFilename() {
         String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
         File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
         if (!file.exists()) {
         file.mkdirs();
         }
         return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
         }
```

When I click the start button this error will occur at the same time start button is got invisible and stop button came to visible. Can anyone tell me why could I get this error?I coded permission in manifest file also.Any help is greatly thankful.

Comment: Did you try `new File(filePath).createNewFile();`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set these permissions in your Manifest file:
`android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and
`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`